# Automatic Redirection?

Tags: list, redirect, sitepages

how can I make a landing site that auto-redirects a user login to their specific client site? based on data from a list. I have created a list with users and their websites

Answer (score 0):

*SP2013/Online (maybe 2010, I can't test)*

Provided you have a List with Text fields for `Account` (notation: username@domain.com ) and `Url` (text url, not hyperlink!)

You can add a Calculated Column with Formula:

```
="<img src=/_layouts/images/blank.gif onload=""{"
&"if('"
&Account
&"'===_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName)this.parentNode.innerHTML='"
&Url
&"';"
&"}"">"
```

Set the datatype to Number to have it output the HTML/JavaScript

Display the **whole List** on your landing page.

If you have configured the `Account` and `Url`   correct, it will display the Url for **one** matching Account

Now for the redirect, Change:

```
&"'===_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName)this.parentNode.innerHTML='"
```

to

```
&"'===_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName)document.location='"
```

Et Voila

How and why this works: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How

#### Or:

You could also use a default `Assigned To` field and a View Filter on [Me]

That would display only one entry (and invoke the above code without the if)

That will work on 2010 as well

But is not as easy to test

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through a few different ways, the recommended way is via server side code via a web part or application page; however, I'll explain the simplest which is via client-side code, Javascript, using CSOM aka JSOM.

On your main page, whatever page you choose, add a Content Editor Webpart. You can either add the code inline into the source or link to it via the webpart properties.

As for your code, I don't have the time to code it up right now, but theory:

**Using jQuery or plain Javascript**:

1. Obtain the current user, your result most likely will return as a
   display name (Smith, John)
2. Invoke SharePoint REST API (web api or listdata.svc) to obtain data from the list containing all user and their URL.
3. Redirect the user to their respectful client site.